# Have rsync only report files which were updated

Tags: rsync

When rsync prints out the details of what it did for each file (using one of the verbose flags) it seems to include both files that were updated and files that were not updated. For example a snippet of my output using the `-v` flag looks like this:

```
rforms.php is uptodate
robots.txt is uptodate
sorry.html
thankyou.html is uptodate
```

I'm only interested about the files that were updated. In the above case that's `sorry.html`. It also prints out directory names as it enters them even if there is no file in that directory that is updated. Is there a way to filter out uptodate files and directories with no updated files from this output?

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe it through grep:

```
rsync -vv (your other rsync options here) | grep -v 'uptodate'
```

Comment: On long running files you will not get progress since grep is not interactive.

Comment: doesn't work for version >= 3.0.7 (see http://serverfault.com/questions/401210/rsync-report-only-uploaded-files#comment418372_401215)

Comment: I want to correct, or at least clarify, what @jeff posted above and what @KarlRichter pointed out. I think the issue is not that `rsync -v` no longer emits the string "uptodate" but rather that you need to use `rsync -vv`. Note the two `v`s. I just verified this works on Ubuntu 14.04 with `rsync` version 3.1.0. @jeff can you update your post to reflect this?

Comment: This one worked well for me with `rsync version 2.6.9` on MacOS Catalina. One oddity I noted was that a few `uptodate` files leaked past the `grep -v 'uptodate'` screen. FWIW, one thing these *leaked* files had in common was that they had "special" characters in the file name. This could probably be fixed...

Answer (score 4):

Rsync's output can be extensively customized, take a look at `rsync --info=help`; `-v` is a fairly coarse way to get information from a modern rsync.

In your case, I'm not sure exactly what you consider "updated" to mean.  For example, deleted on the receiver too? Only files/dirs, but also pipes and symlinks too?  Mod/access times or only content?

As a simple test I suggest you look at: `rsync --info=name1 <other opts>`.

Comment: @Michael How about this:   `rsync -avh --info=NAME1,DEL,PROGRESS1 --delete --ignore-errors /source /target`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take... (work-proven and very happy with it.)

```
rsync -arzihv --stats --progress   \
    /media/frank/foo/              \
    /mnt/backup_drive/    | grep -E '^[^.]|^$'
```

The important bit is the `-i` for itemize.

The grep lets *all* output lines pass (also any summary as in `-h --stats`, also empty ones before that, which benefits legibility) *except* those starting with a dot: These are the ones, that [describe unchanged files](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html):

```
A . means that the item is not being updated  (though  it
    might have attributes that are being modified).
```